# Realice un ciclo de 20 posiciones con datos aleatorios random e indique el número mayor , el menor y el promedio , no sé cómo sacar el promedio

Tags: bucle-for, php7, while, random, importación

Realice un ciclo de 20 posiciones con datos aleatorios random e indique el número mayor , el menor y el promedio , no sé cómo sacar el promedio

```
     import random
     Mayor=Menor=random.randint(1,200)
     for _in range(21):
     Numero=random.randint(1,20)        
     print(Numero)
     
     if Numero>Mayor:
     Mayor=Numero
     
     if Numero<Menor
     Menor=Numero
     
     print(f"El número mayor es :{Mayor}")
     print(f"El número menor es :{Menor}")
```

Comment: El [promedio](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_aritm%C3%A9tica) es la suma de todos los valores divido la cantidad.

Comment: Eso lo entiendo pero no sé cómo realizarlo en una lista ramdom de números aleatorios

Comment: Ah. De la misma manera. Sumas cada uno de los números y los divides por la cantidad. La cantidad sería 21, no 20, ya que `range` comienza a contar desde el 0.

Comment: Muchas gracias si es que son números aleatorios no que los ingrese el usuario

Comment: ¿Tienen relación las etiquetas de tu pregunta con la pregunta en sí? Además, se entiende que son "números aleatorios" pero ¿qué te impide guardar en una variable _cuántos_ números aleatorios generaste como para obtener el promedio?

Comment: esto es php o python? ademas, ya te dijeron, el promedio se calcula de la misma forma.. vas sumando los numeros y al final dividis por la cantidad.. no importa si son aleatorios o no, la forma es la misma...}

Comment: Es phyton en este caso son es un rango de 20 números